# How to avoid extra-space in latex math mode equations

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am working with a very simple `LaTeX` equation of for example `f_(x)=a`. However, when I do `$f(x)=a_1$` - I am getting a huge extra-space before and after the `=` sign. This is annoying. How can remove that? I tried to force it using the `\!` option but that didn't help me at all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a compilable code that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: `f_(x)` will make the first parenthesis a subscript; I don't think it's what you want.

Comment: Edited my question now and thank you.

Comment: that is not what JouleV meant, use a full document, including preamble etc. The effect also depends on the text on the line. So we need to have a document where we can recreate the behaviour you see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my guess as to what is happening.  The first case is the baseline case: `f(x)=a`.  In the second case, the changing of `a` to `a_1` causes a linebreak, which introduces the extra space throughout the line, notably inside the equation.

The 3rd case is possibly a resolution, placing the inline equation in an `\mbox`.  However, while that prevents the equation from being spread out, it forces the extra space to be distributed elsewhere, not necessarily in a pretty fashion.

Perhaps the best approach is to rewrite your sentence so it does not break in a line at an unadvantageous location.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=.5\textwidth
\sloppy
\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi $f(x)=a$. Blah Blah Blah

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi $f(x)=a_1$. Blah Blah

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi \mbox{$f(x)=a_1$}. Blah Blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a better solution and I have marked your answer as ACCEPTED.